# Committing binary files to SVN

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, resources

SVN doesnt commit a library like MySql connector, so when I commit my project it is not uploaded to the server, how can I do this, I how to sync another resources like pictures?

Comment: Changed title to reflect the question more accurately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVN, just like any other source control management system, can handle binary files as well. This should not pose a problem.

Check that the file is not under `.svn-ignore` or any similar ignore flag. Check that any other SVN properties that define the file are set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion can support any type of file, what software are you using to make your commits? If you are using TortoiseSVN: make sure you have the "Show un-versioned files" box checked and that each file you want to commit is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind SVN only commits files marked as added to the project.

I believe you must´ve forgotten to add your file to the repository or, as Yuval A said, maybe it´s on the ignore list.